# How do I get ul-tree items to stay still while sortable()-dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a jQuery based tree menu using jQuery sortable(). Here is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/8KDur/.

As you see, the sortable function works fine.

**But**, the ui-behavior while dragging a tree li-item over the other tree items doesn't work the way I wish too. I want the li-items to stay still and the border between them highlight while dragging. Indicating between which items it will be placed.

So, how do I get the items to stay still while dragging?

I'd rather not use plugins for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `placeholder` option to specify a CSS class to use as the border between the items. Then, set `helper` to `'clone'` which will create a duplicate of the list item you are dragging. By default, jQuery UI will hide the helper using an in-line `display: none`, so it may be necessary to override that if you want the list item to remain visible and static.

http://jsfiddle.net/8KDur/33/

Comment: Thank you! That helped me out. Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/PeterWesterlund/8KDur/43/

Comment: Is it possible to trigger the highlight either between the li-elements or over the div.tree-item-content-element depends on where you dragging? Not at two places the same time. My current code: http://jsfiddle.net/PeterWesterlund/8KDur/70/